# What is the best way to learn SELinux?

Tags: linux, selinux

I want to learn SELinux to a high level, being able to understand the intricacies of domains, types and switching.

What is the best way to go about this? I considered starting with Fedora and a good manual, although as Fedora ships with so many pre-written policies I found it somewhat overwhelming.

Is there a good tutorial or learning distro suited to this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Fedora's SELinux documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux) is a good place to start.  While referring to Fedora 13, the [SELinux User Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/) has plenty of information about how SELinux works.  I also recommend reading [Dan Walsh's Blog](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/), where he talks about SELinux and related issues.  Lastly, drop into `#fedora-selinux` on the FreeNode IRC network, there are often people there who can provide some input.

Comment: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/24/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/index.html is the latest Fedora Users & Administrators Guide (since this answer is still getting hits)

Answer (score 1):

The redhat docs are pretty good
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/part_I-SELinux.html

Also: https://opensource.com/business/13/11/selinux-policy-guide