# How to generate SELinux policies based on logs?

Tags: rhel, selinux

Afaik there is a solution/software that can automatically generate SELinux policies based on logfiles. I just don't know the name of the software/method that can do this..

Comment: I think, I have seen such a post, too. But sadly I can`t remember where that was. Best starting point in UL: [Best way to learn selinux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33744/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-selinux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

audit2allow can generate SELinux policies based on logs:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01

and

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html